# Issue with passing values through state.go

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having trouble passing through a `uid` into the `$state.go` function.

Here is my controller:

```js
.controller('chatCtrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state,$ionicHistory,$stateParams) {

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.session_id= sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');
    var sid = $scope.session_id;
    if($scope.session_id == null){
        $state.go('login');
    }
    else {
        var cload = 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/chat_load.php';
        $http.post(cload, {id : $scope.session_id}).then(function (res){
            $scope.chat = res.data;
        });
        $scope.chat = {};
        $scope.openModal = function(id) {
            $scope.selectedId = id;
            $state.go('chat2',{uid: $scope.selectedId});

        }
    }
})


.controller('chat2Ctrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state,$ionicHistory,$stateParams) {

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.id = {};

    $scope.session_id= sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');
    var sid = $scope.session_id;
    if($scope.session_id == null){
        $state.go('login');
    }
    else {
        var pmloaddd = 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/upml.php';
        $http.post(pmloaddd, {id : $state.params.uid}).then(function (res){
            $scope.pmload = res.data;
        });


     

    }
    
})
```

Here is my app.js:

```js
$stateProvider
.state('chat2', {
   url: '/page9',
   params: {
     uid: null
   },
   templateUrl: 'templates/chat2.html',
   controller: 'chat2Ctrl'
})
```

Comment: Have you tried with $stateParams like `$stateParams.uid`

Comment: Just tried that, no luck :/

Comment: What trouble are you experiencing?

Comment: The uid (user id) is being passed through the state.go controller however its not being recieved in the chat2Ctrl controller

Comment: Anyone? I'm really stumped with this

Comment: you haven't state any url params in the state config

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes

1. Did not add the parameter to the URL property of your state configuration
2. And $state.params.uid is invalid.

Use the below solution.

Your app.js

```
$stateProvider
.state('chat2', {
   url: '/page9/:uid',             //added the parameter here
   params: {
     uid: null
   },
   templateUrl: 'templates/chat2.html',
   controller: 'chat2Ctrl'
})
```

Your else part of the Chat2 controller should be as below

```
if($scope.session_id == null){
        $state.go('login');
    }
    else {
        var pmloaddd = 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/upml.php';
        // modified the below line
        $http.post(pmloaddd, {id : $stateParams.uid}).then(function (res){
            $scope.pmload = res.data;
        });
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/CyhAj2zoLfp9rpuyqfcF?p=preview)**

Comment: You can have a look at the demo !!

Comment: Don't you think I've already looked at that. Is there any need for anger!!

Comment: Yes, mind if we carry this on once I'm home back from work? :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass it with url and then you can  access it like--

> $stateParams.

```
$stateProvider
 .state('chat2', {
   url: '/page9/:uid',
     controller:'name of yout controller',
     controller: function($stateParams){
     $stateParams.uid  //*** Exists! ***//
     }
      });
```

then you can access like this:-

> $stateparams.uid at controller.

You can also refer this link--[Url routing--stateParams Service](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service)